# Angular Component: unable to mix styleUrls and styles

Tags: angular, components

I'm using Angular 9.0.4 and somehow i can't make my Compontent use both, styleUrls and styles.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'notificationButton',
  templateUrl: 'notificationButton.component.html', 
  providers: [ExplorerService],
  styles: ['#notificationButton: { display: none!important; border-left: 1px solid white; padding: 15px 5px; height:75px; }'],
  styleUrls: [
    '../scss/navigation-button.scss'
  ]
})
```

According to the docs it should be possible as they specifically mention it:

> You can specify more than one styles file or even a combination of
>   styles and styleUrls.

https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#style-files-in-component-metadata

**EDIT:** this seems to be a bug in the current version 9.0.4, just stick to inline styles until resolved

Comment: your quotes in styles are inverse single quotes?

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: forget my comment, not work for me, (Angular get the last defined, see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ofrbfu?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts (you can interchange the position of url and stylesUrl )

Comment: @AliF50 no error